# Having trouble with the Parametrization of a line

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to parametrize the frontier of a rectangle. So far, I have that $C_1$ goes from $(0,3) to (0,-3)$ So the parametrization would be:

$(0,3) + t(0, -3-3) = (0,3) + (0, -6t) = (0, 3 -6t) $

with $ 0 \le t \le 1 $. Is that right?

$C_2$ would go from $(0,-3)$ to $(5, -3) $, so I wrote :

$(0,-3) + t(5, -6) = (5t, -3 -6t)$ but I am not sure how to give the range for $t$. Because, there should be a $t$ which would give me (5, -3). That forces $t$ to be 1 in the first column, and at the same time forces $t$ to be 0 in the second column (im talking about susbstituting in $ (5t,-3-6t)$). And that is a contradiction. What am I not understanding?

Comment: First mistake:  $3 + (-6t) = 3 - 6t \ne -3t$.

Comment: $t\vec{v} + (1-t)\vec{w}$ parametrizes the line from $\vec{v}$ (when $t=0$) to $\vec{w}$ (when $t=1$).

Comment: i corrected it                                                         -----------------------------------------------